# HTML5 Canvas manipulate letters with mouse

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML5 Canvas, as I have very little experience with it.  What I'm trying to accomplish is have about 50 letter D's, different sizes and color moving around on the screen.  When a user gets close to these letters with the mouse I want the letters to speed up and move around.  Does anyone have a good tutorial on this?

Comment: seek a framework or you'll have too long a path to go. In your case,  i'll go for createJs, using the easelJS module, which could easily handle the mouse and the letters that you can define as display objects. See here to get an idea : http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you comfortable with these javascript concepts?

- arrays,
- objects,
- event handlers,
- timers,
- prototyping,
- pseudo-classes

If you feel comfortable with these javascript concepts, check this demo out:

Start the demo and then hold mouse down to create "particles".

The particles will be repelled by mouse proximity.

http://soofw.com/demos/fountains/

It works with circle "Ball" objects, but you can adapt the code to draw D's instead:

```
Ball.prototype.draw=function() {
    surface.context.font = this.font;  // add the font property to the Ball class
    surface.context.fillStyle = this.color.v
    surface.context.fillText("D",this.x,this.y);
}
```

And so on...

If you're not comfortable with the code, do as @Vincent Piel suggests:  google = html canvas library.